# CDI end JMS endpoints: @Produces transacted Session issue

Tags: jakarta-ee, jms, cdi

I'm trying to send/produce JMS messages from a simple Stateless EJB. For this I'm using CDI to produce and inject the JMS resources (`ConnectionFactory`, `Connection` and `Session`). Exactly as described in the [Weld doc - JavaEE integration, JMS enpoints](https://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/ee.html#_jms_endpoints).

The point is if I produce the JMS Session as `trasacted` the ,message is not sent (or commited) by my EJB. No error occurs.

CDI Resource producer:

```
@Produces
@ItemQualifier
public Session createJMSSession(@ItemQualifier Connection connection) throws JMSException {
    return connection.createSession(true, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
}
```

EJB JMS producer method:

```
public void pushItem(Item newItem) throws Exception {
    log.info("Sending " + newItem.getDescricao());
    log.info("Session Transacted? " + mineracaoSession.getTransacted());

    ObjectMessage message = session.createObjectMessage();

    message.setObject(newItem);
    producer.send(message);

    log.info("Message sent!");
}
```

If I change the Producer method to create non-transacted JMS Session the messages is sent (commited) normally.

I would like to understand why my EJB does not send/commit messages when the JMS session is `transacted`. All EJB methods is by default transacted, right?

Comment: Just curious, what EE version are you using?  If you're on EE 7, you may want to use the new simplified JMS interfaces.

Comment: I'm using JavaEE 6 on JBossAS 7

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in this [JBoss Forum thread](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/213629).

In sum if you want a transacted JMS Session you have to either control (commit/rollback) the tx by your self or use a JMS `XAConnectionFactory`. In my case I was using the default `InVM` ConnectionFactory which is not XA. So, in this case even using an EJB I had to invoke `session.commit()` explicitly. Or change my ConnectionFactory resource to the XA one.